# Use SQL or TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Please see the DDL below:

```
CREATE TABLE Groups 
(
    GroupID integer not null, 
    Dataset int, 
    URN int, 
    DateAdded datetime
)

INSERT INTO Groups(1,1,100,'2010-01-01')
INSERT INTO Groups(1,1,191,'2011-01-01')
INSERT INTO Groups(1,1,65,'2012-01-01')
INSERT INTO Groups(1,2,121,'2013-01-01')

INSERT INTO Groups(2,1,87,'2010-01-01')
INSERT INTO Groups(2,1,1081,'2011-01-01')
INSERT INTO Groups(2,1,32,'2012-01-01')
INSERT INTO Groups(2,1,16,'2013-01-01')
INSERT INTO Groups(2,2,66,'2013-01-01')
```

I am trying to return a table like this:

```
100 191
100 65
87  1081
87  32
87  16
```

Column 1 is the group ID and column 2 is the URN.  The list meets the criteria:

1. Get all records with a dataset of 1 from the group
2. Always display the oldest URN (using dateadded) in column 1 (where dataset=1). In column 2 put another URN from the group (where dataset=1)
3. Ensure all URNs (WHERE dataset=1) from the group appear once in column 2 except for the URN that appears in column 1

I believe I have to do this programmatically (using TSQL), however I wondered if there was a way of doing it with SQL.

Comment: Your results do not match your stated requirements.  Based on your requirements you should only get 2 records back (one for each group).

Comment: @D Stanley, I have edited the requirements to try and make it clearer.

Comment: It still does not match.  The oldest URN for group 1 would be 100, and the oldest from group 2 would be 78.  You are showing all records _except_ the oldest one.

Comment: @D Stanley, I see.  I have edited it again.  Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `FIRST_VALUE` to get the oldest `URN` for each group:

```
SELECT FIRST_VALUE(URN) OVER (PARTITION BY GroupID ORDER BY DateAdded) AS OldestURN, URN
FROM Groups
WHERE Dataset = 1
```

**Output:**

```
OldestURN   URN
---------------
100         100
100         191
100         65
87          87
87          1081
87          32
87          16
```

Then, simply nest the above query inside another one to get only records with `OldestURN <> URN`:

```
SELECT OldestURN, URN
FROM (
   SELECT FIRST_VALUE(URN) OVER (PARTITION BY GroupID ORDER BY DateAdded) AS OldestURN, 
          URN
   FROM Groups
   WHERE Dataset = 1 ) t
WHERE OldestURN <> URN
```

**Output:**

```
OldestURN   URN
---------------
100         191
100         65
87          1081
87          32
87          16
```

Comment: Thanks.  I think this may do it.  +1.  I will test tomorrow and report back.